# Should Create/Delete/Update Methods have own save method? Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I read that EF is itself a unit of work and and repository so I really don't want to make a repository layer and another UoW unless truly necessary.

I was wondering about this though. I have a City Service and a Venue Service.

I have a FindVenue method

```
public void FindVenue()
{
    // find venue in db
    // If not in db - find from 3rd party api
    // If from 3rd party api check if city exits in db
   //  If city does not exist create a city record in db
   //  If venue does not exist create a new venue record in db
   context.SaveChanges();
}
```

Now I am wondering should the CreateCity method have  `context.SaveChanges();` or should it just add it to the DbSet and then when in FindVenue is done creating the new venue it could just insert both records.

That way only 1 call to the db and if one fails they both get rolled back(you of course can make the argument that these are separate and if the city can be inserted then why not do it)

One problem I see though is that if someone else calls say the CreateCity from the controller as I could have a direct way of inserting a City into my database then the controller would need to have to do the `context.SaveChanges()` which would be bad or I would have to have a new method called CreateAndSaveCity();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would not recommend calling save changes more than you have to just to share code (i.e. only call it once for `FindVenue()`).

To solve the problem of other methods wanting to save cities, here are a couple of ideas...

**Option 1:** create an overload method of create city (like you suggested, something like `CreateAndSaveCity`) that would call the first method `CreateCity` (which does not save changes) and then save changes

```
public void FindVenue()
{
    // find venue in db
    // If not in db - find from 3rd party api
    // If from 3rd party api check if city exits in db
    // If city does not exist...
    CreateCity(context);
    // If venue does not exist create a new venue record in db
    context.SaveChanges();
}

public void CreateCity(YourContext context)
{
    // Create city, don't save changes
}

public void CreateAndSaveCity(YourContext context)
{
    CreateCity();
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

In this case, if you want to create a city from the controller elsewhere, you can call `CreateAndSaveCity(context)`

**Option 2:** Have the `CreateCity` method take an optional boolean parameter that indicates whether changes should be saved. You could have the default be true or false for the optional parameter depending on your most common use case, or make it required if you want to ensure that it's always specified explicitly.

```
public void FindVenue()
{
    // find venue in db
    // If not in db - find from 3rd party api
    // If from 3rd party api check if city exits in db
    // If city does not exist...
    CreateCity(context);
    // If venue does not exist create a new venue record in db
    context.SaveChanges();
}

public void CreateCity(YourContext context, bool saveChanges = false)
{
    // Create city
    if (saveChanges) {
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

In this case, if you want to create a city from the controller elsewhere, you can call `CreateCity(context, true)`

Personally, I prefer option 2, but it's mostly a matter of semantics.

Also, regarding your comment:

> you of course can make the argument that these are separate and if the
>   city can be inserted then why not do it

This depends on the needs of your business logic. But even in this case, you could still save changes after checking whether the venue should be created (and creating if needed). If you don't actually *need* the city to be saved separately (for example, to get its id after insertion to set a foreign key), there is no reason to make a database round trip.

Comment: yes, I like option 2 as well, might as well make sure of the optional parameter feature! For id's I have my own GuidComb method that generates a Guid on server side thus no round trips. I come from nhibernate background where GuidComb is recommended as doing the database round trip kills the UoW in nhibernate and then you can't rollback.

Answer (score 0):

Do `SaveChanges` in `CreateCity()` and wrap it in a `TransactionScope`.

```
public void FindVenue()
{
   using (var trans = new TransactionScope()) {
       CreateCity();
       // some code to add your venue...
       // ...
       context.SaveChanges();
       trans.Commit();
   }
}
```

Comment: Do you mean SaveChagnes in FindVeneue() not CreateCity?

Comment: I mean in both methods.